# Regex to check for string with 2 or more spaces

Tags: java, regex

I tried to write a regex for validating following string,
    **good  <3 spaces>    morning**

The regex I tried was **\s{2,}.** However the regex match failed

Comment: your regex seems fine

Comment: Your pattern is fine, please provide the code how you match it

Comment: Escape the \ in your regex & you're good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string must match entirly

```
"Good   morning".matches(".*\\s{2}.*");
```

Comment: That should be: `\\s{2,}`. Note the comma.

Comment: No, one of the `.*` will eat the extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

How about "\Agood   morning\Z"?

It might seem too obvious, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
".*\s\s.*"
```

- Any sequence of character (potentially empty)
- a space
- a space
- any sequence of character(potentially empty)

Comment: That is not a valid Java string.

Comment: He just asked a regexp, no code and this "good <3 spaces> morning" is not a valid string either.